# How do you play or record audio (to .WAV) on Linux in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, gstreamer

> Hello, I've been looking for a way to **play** and **record** audio on a Linux (preferably Ubuntu) system. I'm currently working on a front-end to a [voice recognition toolkit](https://www.launchpad.net/cmusphinx-train) that'll automate a few steps required to adapt a voice model for `PocketSphinx` and `Julius`.

Suggestions of alternative means of audio input/output are **welcome**, as well as a fix to the **bug shown below**.

Here is the current code I've used so far to play a `.WAV` file:

```
void Engine::sayText ( const string OutputText ) {
    string audioUri = "temp.wav";
    string requestUri = this->getRequestUri( OPENMARY_PROCESS , OutputText.c_str( ) );
    int error , audioStream;
    pa_simple *pulseConnection;
    pa_sample_spec simpleSpecs;
    simpleSpecs.format = PA_SAMPLE_S16LE;
    simpleSpecs.rate = 44100;
    simpleSpecs.channels = 2;

    eprintf( E_MESSAGE , "Generating audio for '%s' from '%s'..." , OutputText.c_str( ) , requestUri.c_str( ) );
    FILE* audio = this->getHttpFile( requestUri , audioUri );
    fclose(audio);
    eprintf( E_MESSAGE , "Generated audio.");

    if ( ( audioStream = open( audioUri.c_str( ) , O_RDONLY ) ) < 0 ) {
        fprintf( stderr , __FILE__": open() failed: %s\n" , strerror( errno ) );
        goto finish;
    }

    if ( dup2( audioStream , STDIN_FILENO ) < 0 ) {
        fprintf( stderr , __FILE__": dup2() failed: %s\n" , strerror( errno ) );
        goto finish;
    }

    close( audioStream );

    pulseConnection = pa_simple_new( NULL , "AudioPush" , PA_STREAM_PLAYBACK , NULL , "openMary C++" , &simpleSpecs , NULL , NULL , &error );

    for (int i = 0;;i++ ) {
        const int bufferSize = 1024;
        uint8_t audioBuffer[bufferSize];
        ssize_t r;
        eprintf( E_MESSAGE , "Buffering %d..",i);
        /* Read some data ... */
        if ( ( r = read( STDIN_FILENO , audioBuffer , sizeof (audioBuffer ) ) ) <= 0 ) {
            if ( r == 0 ) /* EOF */
                break;

            eprintf( E_ERROR , __FILE__": read() failed: %s\n" , strerror( errno ) );
    if ( pulseConnection )
        pa_simple_free( pulseConnection );

        }

        /* ... and play it */
        if ( pa_simple_write( pulseConnection , audioBuffer , ( size_t ) r , &error ) < 0 ) {
            fprintf( stderr , __FILE__": pa_simple_write() failed: %s\n" , pa_strerror( error ) );
    if ( pulseConnection )
        pa_simple_free( pulseConnection );

        }

        usleep(2);

    }
    /* Make sure that every single sample was played */
    if ( pa_simple_drain( pulseConnection , &error ) < 0 ) {
        fprintf( stderr , __FILE__": pa_simple_drain() failed: %s\n" , pa_strerror( error ) );
    if ( pulseConnection )
        pa_simple_free( pulseConnection );
    }    
}
```

NOTE: If you want the rest of the code to this file, you can download it [here](http://launchpad.net/libopenmary-c++/trunk/0.3a/+download/libopenmary_0%2Bbzr20110123%2B4.tar.gz) directly from Launchpad.

Update: I tried using `GStreamermm`, and this won't work:

```
    Glib::RefPtr<Pipeline> pipeline;
    Glib::RefPtr<Element> sink, filter, source;
    Glib::RefPtr<Gio::File> audioSrc = Gio::File::create_for_path(uri);

    pipeline = Pipeline::create("audio-playback");
    source = ElementFactory::create_element("alsasrc","source");
    filter = ElementFactory::create_element("identity","filter");
    sink = ElementFactory::create_element("alsasink","sink");
    //sink->get_property("file",audioSrc);
    if (!source || !filter || !sink){
        showErrorDialog("Houston!","We got a problem.");
        return;
    }
    pipeline->add(source)->add(filter)->add(sink);
    source->link(sink);

    pipeline->set_state(Gst::STATE_PLAYING);
    showInformation("Close this to stop recording");
    pipeline->set_state(Gst::STATE_PAUSED);
```

Comment: This would be a better question for [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I'd consider the gstreamer library for playing and recording. But I suppose that Pulse should also have a recording options?

Comment: @Michael I posted it on the programming one, because I assumed it was programming related.

@Petriborg Can you demonstrate a means of doing it or a **good** link on how to do so? GStreamer seems to only support OGG and CMUSphinx needs WAV files.

Comment: Where is the bug? what do you get when you try to compile? What do you want in an alternative?

Comment: @Tom it's not a programming bug; it's more like missing code.
When it's compiled and run (you can try by heading to the Launchpad, downloading and running), instead of hearing 'Welcome to Speech', you get PEEEP! And I want something that works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The "Hello World" application in the GStreamer documentation](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-helloworld.html#section-helloworld) shows how to play an Ogg/Vorbis file.  To make this work with WAV files, you can simply replace "oggdemux" with "wavparse" and replace "vorbisdec" with "identity" (the identity plugin does nothing -- it's just a placeholder).

To install development support for GStreamer (on Ubuntu)...

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev
```

You need the following on the gcc command-line to enable the use of GStreamer libraries...

```
$(pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10)
```

By the way, you may find it useful to use "gst-launch" for prototyping GStreamer pipelines before writing the code.

```
## recording
gst-launch-0.10 autoaudiosrc ! wavenc ! filesink location=temp.wav

## playback
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=temp.wav ! wavparse ! autoaudiosink
```

A feature of GStreamer that may be useful for voice recognition is that it is easy to insert audio quality filters into a pipeline -- so you could, for example, reduce noise that might otherwise be in the recording.  A pointer to a list of the GStreamer "good" plugins is [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/).

Also of interest, "PocketSphinx" (which seems to be related to your project) already has some GStreamer integration.  See [Using PocketSphinx with GStreamer and Python](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/gstreamer)

Comment: I haven't used Python for this application; it's mainly code in C++, as it's the language I know best, but you've been a tremendous help and I'll reply with my status.

Comment: Also, I'm attempting to implement a super simple way of adapting voice models for PocketSphinx/CMUSphinx.

Answer (score 1):

GStreamer/Pulse/JACK are great.
For simple and fast things you might use SoX http://sox.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Do they have an API? I can't use the command line; I need to be able to control volume as well.

Comment: @Jacky Alcine: libsox  is  a  library  of sound sample file format readers/writers and sound effects processors. It is mainly developed for use by SoX but  is useful for any sound application.

Yes, SoX can be used as a lib too - just llok in the archive for details